# document scrolls over html height

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-router

I am using vue router , and by some reasons(i dont know why its happen) when i route from one component with some height to another , the scroll in document exist even the html tag height is over.
I dont use any css overrides. The html tag wraps the body element by default.

But the problem is browser scroll it down(to old page maximum size).

For example is some page state had the 100 elements,but the current have only 10, the browser scroll page down to the empty (like there is 100 elements).
The html tag wrap the body,the body size is normal,its wrap only 10 elements.

Is there any funtions to force page size.

The following doesnot work :

```
html.scrollHeight=body.scrollHeight
```

Seems like that only have the getter.
[image]

The way why is size of container changes is pagination .
Also only one way i am using router methods inside is router.push to add hash (backend) property to the path.

```
 window.api.product.list
        .get(this.request_params)
        .then((data) => {
          debugger;
          if (this.page == 1) {
            this.items = data.list;
          } else {
            this.items = [...this.items, ...data.list];
          }

          if (!this.initial) {
            if (data.hash) {
              this.$router.push({ query: { hash: data.hash } });
            } else {
              const query = Object.assign({}, this.$route.query);
              delete query.hash;
              this.$router.replace({ query });
            }
            global.appData.dispatch("products/setHash", data.hash);
          }
```

The router config

```
 const routes = [
      {
        path: "/lk/catalog/show/:code/",
        component: catalogItemPage,
        name: "catalog-item-page",
        props: (route) => ({ code: route.params.code }),
      },
      { path: "/lk/catalog/:category+", component: catalogGeneral, name: "catalog-categories" },
    ];

    const router = new VueRouter({
      mode: "history",
      routes,
      scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        console.log("scroll behaviour");
        if (savedPosition) {
          return savedPosition;
        } else {
          return { x: 0, y: 0 };
        }
      },
    });

    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
      if (to.name == "catalog-categories" && from.name == "catalog-categories" && to.path != from.path) {
        global.appData.commit("products/setDefaults");
      }
      global.appData.commit("catalog/changeCurrentPath", to.path);
      next();
    });
```

The items,page accessing via vuex. Set defaults set items array to [], and page to 1.

Comment: Please provide some code details.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Comment: Hello, assigning a value to `Element.scrollHeight` does not work, as it is a `read-only` property. I think it would make sense to provide a [example] so that other people can help you.

Comment: I fix the bug causing that scroll bug. It was "NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location" error from router. Becouse every time i add hash to page via router.push, i do not check the current hash in path query is equal or not to the new. But the quetion still alive.If vue-router manipulates with scroll size,there is some ways to set scroll size of the document. Obviosly its not by the scrollHeight prop,becouse that is readonly.